# Build a certificate context from a .pem file containing certificate and private key

Tags: c++, windows, x509, cryptoapi, schannel

I'm developing a C++/Windows TLS client.

I can build a certificate context for the server certificate in this way:

```
    ReadFile(hFile, cert, 8192, &len, NULL);
    CryptStringToBinary(cert, readLen, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY, binCert, &binLen, NULL, NULL);
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, (BYTE*)binCert, binLen);
```

but if I try do to the same with a client certificate (.pem file containing certificate and private key) I got a fail.
I think this is due to the fact that server as only one base64 section

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

while the client has two:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----
-----END PRIVATE KEY----

But that's just my guess.

Can someone provide a code snip that builds a certificate context from this kind of .pem file?

Acceptable code must not parse directly the file, I mean I don't want to parse the file to separate certificate from key.

Thanks!

Let me include an example of pem I would like to use:

```
Bag Attributes
friendlyName: client
localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 38 34 38 33 33 35 35 39 31 30 39 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
friendlyName: client
localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 38 34 38 33 33 35 35 39 31 30 39 
subject=/C=it/ST=mi/L=milan/O=hat/OU=red/CN=clientzilla
issuer=/C=it/ST=mi/L=milan/O=hat/OU=red/CN=clientzilla
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231178/load-an-x509-pem-file-into-windows-cryptoapi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load an X509 PEM file into Windows CryptoApi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231178/load-an-x509-pem-file-into-windows-cryptoapi)

Comment: My .pem file contains the key AND the certificate, this case is different from the above

Comment: You have to split these sections in separate files. CryptoAPI can't handle more than one headered base64 section.