# rsa encryption in windows crypto and decryption in openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, rsa, cryptoapi

I have a problem in exchanging public key between "OpenSSL" and "Windows CryptoAPI". The public key is exported from OpenSSL in pem format.My program is written in c++. I get the public key and load it by "CryptoAPI". After loading the public key, I encrypt some data and send them to the other application. The other application can not decrypt the received data by own private key. please help me to find the solution.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcJXxao6OzesjaM5VnsYTnHWUN
z8dosWEETARH6NOqq+hAoMscsv+2MgT0oOYKLf/c8i37YFXnswEan78QnWYO3jtX
UHfJgXcLcMz7o3lX3OwNqRXgXW6Db95EjPEnLuPCJ2Pafu9E75ZMglkgw9MrIAik
XKL9u2dc9fkbc7FptQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Source code:

```
_ServerContextHandle = NULL;
_EncryptionKeyHandle = NULL;

void Initialize(char* inPublicKeyByPemFormat)
{
    HCRYPTPROV serverContextHandle;

    bool result = CryptAcquireContextW(&serverContextHandle, nullptr, nullptr, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) == TRUE;

    if (result)
    {
        _ServerContextHandle = serverContextHandle;

        byte derPublicKey[2048];
        DWORD derPublicKeyLength = 2048;

        result = CryptStringToBinaryA(inPublicKeyByPemFormat, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, derPublicKey, &derPublicKeyLength, nullptr, nullptr) == TRUE;

        CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO* publicKeyInfo = nullptr;
        DWORD publicKeyInfoLength;

        if(result)
        {
            result = CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, derPublicKey, derPublicKeyLength, CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, nullptr, &publicKeyInfo, &publicKeyInfoLength) == TRUE;
        }

        HCRYPTKEY encryptionKeyHandle;

        if(result)
        {
            result = CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(_ServerContextHandle, X509_ASN_ENCODING, publicKeyInfo, &encryptionKeyHandle) == TRUE;
        }

        LocalFree(publicKeyInfo);

        if (result)
        {
            _EncryptionKeyHandle = encryptionKeyHandle;
        }
    }
}


byte* EncryptData(byte* inData, DWORD inDataLength, DWORD* outLength) const
{
    byte* result = nullptr;

    *outLength = 0;

    DWORD length = inDataLength;

    result = CloneByteArray(inData, inDataLength);

    if (!CryptEncrypt(_EncryptionKeyHandle, NULL, TRUE, 0, result, &length, length))
    {
        delet result;

        result = new byte[length];

        CopyByteArray(inData, result, inDataLength);

        *outLength = inDataLength;

        if (!CryptEncrypt(_EncryptionKeyHandle, NULL, TRUE, 0, result, outLength, length))
        {
            delete result;

            result = nullptr;

            *outLength = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *outLength = length;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Without the necessary information we cannot debug, even if we would like to debug your code (please debug this is not a question, it's a request for help).

Comment: In your second function inside its first if statement you are deleting the result value but you did not spell it correctly.

Comment: You should state where the failure is in the code above. Is it `CryptDecodeObjectEx` or `CryptImportPublicKeyInfo` or something else? You should validate the public key after loading it. It may mean you need to load a test key pair to ensure correctness. OpenSSL is big endian, and CAPI is little endian. You should probably start with [openssl capi rsa endian site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+capi+rsa+endian+site%3Astackoverflow.com). And see [Load an X509 PEM file into Windows CryptoApi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1231178/608639) in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CryptEncrypt`, for reasons that probably made sense to the author at the time, writes the bytes down backwards. Or, rather, it writes them in byte minor/little-endian order whereas almost every other cryptography library (including the Windows CNG `BCryptEncrypt` and `NCryptEncrypt` routines) writes them in byte major/big-endian order.

So you need to reverse data coming out of `CryptEncrypt`, and reverse it going in to `CryptDecrypt`.

For example, in .NET Core's [RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Csp/System/Security/Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.Windows.cs,e10cb5dc47fd7fb4) it calls [CapiHelper.EncryptKey](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Csp/System/Security/Cryptography/CapiHelper.Windows.cs,73106684215289a8) which calls `CryptEncrypt` then `Array.Reverse` before returning.

The [CryptEncrypt documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379924(v=vs.85).aspx) has as the last sentence in the Remarks section

> The ciphertext is returned in little-endian format.

Comment: Thanks for reply