# CryptDecodeObjectEx fails with CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, cryptography

I am trying to verify a HMAC but CryptDecodeObjectEx is returning an error.

First, I have exported a PEM from a PFX.  I export via .NET using

```
pem = Convert.ToBase64String(x509Cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, password))
```

I write this to a file between '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

Then I use CryptStringToBinaryA to load it into a binary buffer in order to pass it to CryptDecodeObjectEx to get the X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO.

But that is where it fails.  It returns CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG.

```
CHAR SIGN_KEY[] = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                  "MIIFWjCCA..................\n"
                  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

if (CryptStringToBinaryA((LPCSTR)SIGN_KEY, sizeof(SIGN_KEY), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, NULL, &out, NULL, NULL)) {
    bin = (PBYTE)HALLOC(out);
    if (bin) {
        if (CryptStringToBinaryA((LPCSTR)SIGN_KEY, sizeof(SIGN_KEY), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, bin, &out, NULL, NULL)) {

            //This fails here with 0x8009310B (CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG - ASN.1 bad tag value met)
            //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            if (CryptDecodeObjectEx(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, bin, out, CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &cpki, &out)) {
                if (CryptDecodeObjectEx(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, cpki->PublicKey.pbData, cpki->PublicKey.cbData, CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, *key, kl)) {
```

In VB.Net I can use the exact same certificate string and create a new X509 certificate which I then use with a RSACryptoServiceProvider in order to verify the signature.  Pseudo code is as follows:

```
x509 = New X509Certificate2(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SIGN_KEY))

Dim rsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
rsa.FromXmlString(x509.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(False))
Return rsa.VerifyData(MessageBytes, New SHA256CryptoServiceProvider(), SignatureBytes)
```

That works so I'm assuming CryptStringToBinaryA is not processing the certificate string properly but still returning TRUE.

Is there a special format for .NET exported PEMs to be imported into the C/C++ CryptApi?

Comment: yoi need call `CryptImportPublicKeyInfo` in place `CryptDecodeObjectEx(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB` or, if use CNG - `CryptDecodeObjectEx` with `CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB` instead `RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB`

Comment: Why did you close this question?  I've done by research and that does not answer the question.  Re-open it.

Comment: but because answer exist - how i say - replace `RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB` to `CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB` and use cng api. or call `CryptImportPublicKeyInfo`. or look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803333/6401656 or [this](https://github.com/rbmm/PEM/blob/main/legacy_pem.cpp#L22) or [this](https://github.com/rbmm/PEM/blob/main/pem.cpp#L172)

Comment: CryptImportPublicKeyInfo is deprecated!  RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB is the second step after getting the key info.  You have to get the key info first before using RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB.

Comment: `CryptImportPublicKeyInfo` and so what ? all legacy crypto api is depredecated. your `RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB` also depredetacated. use in this case `CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB`

Comment: replace `CryptDecodeObjectEx(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB, cpki->PublicKey.pbData, cpki->PublicKey.cbData,...)` to `CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB, cpki->PublicKey.pbData, cpki->PublicKey.cbData..)`

Comment: `PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO cpki` in your code. and direct used in `CryptImportPublicKeyInfo` or use `CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB`. *CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG* because it formatted not as `RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB` but as `CNG_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB` - replace code as in my previous comment - erros is gone ?

Comment: No.  You have to read X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO BEFORE you read the BLOB.  The error is at X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO.

Comment: you at begin must say - which exactly api call is fail - you not do this

Comment: if you have certificate - you need use `X509_CERT_TO_BE_SIGNED` instead `X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO` as i point you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67665721/cryptdecodeobjectex-fails-with-crypt-e-asn1-badtag#comment119603082_67665721) - look again for [this](https://github.com/rbmm/PEM/blob/main/legacy_pem.cpp#L22) or [this](https://github.com/rbmm/PEM/blob/main/pem.cpp#L172)

Comment: *I'm assuming CryptStringToBinaryA is not processing the certificate string properly but still returning TRUE* of course this is wrong. and look like you here have not certificate but PFX - so need use `PFXImportCertStore` (and check with `PFXIsPFXBlob`)